# Смена надписей у блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть такая вот работа: http://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/5q6p2ypz/2/

При наведении курсора выезжает текст.

Как сделать подписи статичными, при наведении меняющимися на другие?

Сейчас (у первых двух) они меняются, но всё равно затем исчезают.

Вот код:

```
var thumbnail = {
                imgIncrease : 100, 
                effectDuration : 300, 
                imgWidth : $('.thumbnailWrapper ul li').find('img').width(), 
                imgHeight : $('.thumbnailWrapper ul li').find('img').height() 

            };
            $('.thumbnailWrapper ul li').css({ 

                'width' : thumbnail.imgWidth, 
                'height' : thumbnail.imgHeight 

            });

            $('.thumbnailWrapper ul li').hover(function(){

                $(this).find('img').stop().animate({
                    width: parseInt(thumbnail.imgWidth) + thumbnail.imgIncrease,
                    left: thumbnail.imgIncrease/2*(-1),
                    top: thumbnail.imgIncrease/2*(-1)

                },
                                                   { 

                    "duration": thumbnail.effectDuration,
                    "queue": false



                }); 
            $(".sss").css("display", "none")
            $(this).find('.caption:not(:animated)').slideDown(thumbnail.effectDuration);
            }, function(){
                $(this).find('img').animate({
                    width: thumbnail.imgWidth,
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0
                }, thumbnail.effectDuration);
                $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(thumbnail.effectDuration);
                $(".sss").css("display", "inline")
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно заменить в коде первую строчку (вторую такую же не трогать):

```
$(".sss").css("display", "none")
```

на эту:

```
$(this).find(".sss").css("display", "none");
```

Обновление: всплытие надписи. Меняем строчки так:

```
//$(this).find(".sss").css("display", "none");
$(this).find('.sss:not(:animated)').slideUp(thumbnail.effectDuration);

//$(".sss").css("display", "inline")
$(this).find('.sss').slideDown(thumbnail.effectDuration);
```

Comment: Спасибо,а Вы не подскажите,как сделать,что бы одна уезжала,а другая выезжала,а не так как сейчас у меня,через display none

Comment: @zkolya обновил ответ

Comment: очень выручили.Спасибо большое!